# How do I send my finished website to my client?

Tags: html, web, dns, client, host

I've been learning web development, and I would say that I'm at a point now where I consistently make websites the way I want. However, I have one last hurdle that I can't find any answer on  the internet for. Basically, from what I've seen, on Fiver and such, web developers directly connect the commissioned website to the clients domain and host, and then all the client has to do is go to the domain.

**My question is essentially just that - how would I get my final finished product to my client?**

I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I genuinely cannot find any answer for this. Thank you!

Comment: That's going to depend.  What language(s) are you using?  If it's just static HTML/CSS/Javascript you can host anywhere and just FTP in.  Things get more complicated if you've got a back-end requiring databases/PHP/ASP/whatever.

Comment: I'm using vanilla JS and normal HTML and CSS. So should I just find a tutorial online on FTP and that should be good?

Comment: Yes, assuming wherever you're hosting it offers FTP access which is pretty common.  Do you/the client currently have a web host?

Comment: No, I don't have a client yet. I just wanted this information beforehand so I could be prepared and not stress over it at the last second. However, for me personally, I'm thinking of using BlueHost.

Comment: BlueHost offers FTP access https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/upload-site so all you should have to do is drop the HTML/CSS/Javascript files into the root directory and you'll be set.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly the answer I needed. Thank you very much!